# how to check the child process running of a parent PID in windows?

Tags: python, robotframework

I need to get the child process running for a parent PID. How can we check from command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tasklist` in cmd to get the PID's of all the processes running in the system. Another command to achieve the same is:

```
wmic process get Caption,ParentProcessId,ProcessId
```

Comment: I was trying to kill all the child process with the help of taskkill command and also need it to make it work on ubuntu too. Could you please help me with the Linux equivalent of this command:
taskkill /F /PID 1342 /T